# One database, two web application

Tags: java, database

Can 2 separate webapp(java) use the same db(postgres)?

Could be it a problem? Are there any suggestions about it? Using "lock" in the query could be enough?

Comment: "Yes" to both of your first two questions.

Comment: remove the word 'web' from your question and note the result....

Comment: Are you talking about 'database' or 'database-schema'?

Comment: database-schema, then same tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two applications using one database is almost exactly the same as one application using several connections to it, so you are probably already doing it. All the possible problems are exactly the same. The database won't even know whether the connections are made from one application or the other.

Comment: I think it is not completely true and it depends on the way of access to the database. For example if you use JPA and a singleton instance of the EntityManager, it may not automatically get the updates made from the second application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You might have a problem if the two applications have tables that are called the same, for example if both applications have a table called 'user'. It is considered good style to prefix table names for this exact reason, so app 1 might have a table called 'app1_user' and so on.

Long answer short: If the table names do not overlap, then there is no problem.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. I have a development server that only allows a limited number of databases, but i have several web applications that need to connect to a database. 

Knowing that there will be no conflict as long as they are reading/writing to different tables, is perfect. 

Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use same DB for 2 web apps. And there could be a problem while concurrent read/write transactions which can also happen even when you do not have multiple web apps accessing same database. You can refer to [this](http://www.postgresql.org/files/developer/concurrency.pdf) document for avoiding it in postgres.

Comment: With PostgreSQL, you have good guarantees about data visibility, so i think read/write interactions are not a problem. However, write/write can be - if two transactions both try to update the same row, one will fail to commit.

Comment: yes , only read is trivial , many read and one write at a time is almost trivial and multiple writes is where the real issue is.